# How to upgrade GCC from 4.x.x to GCC 5.x.x in RHEL?

Tags: linux, rhel

My current version of GCC:
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

How to upgrade the GCC to 5.X.X

Comment: Why GCC5, the current version is GCC7. You could compile it from its source code (but take some time to read how to do that).

Comment: Is there a direct command to upgrade to gcc7 instead of compile from the source code?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you need to search for some backport, or some binary package. BTW, why do you use such an old distribution?

Comment: So the software management does not offer a newer version? And you failed to find a repository offering a newer version? Have a try searching on SUSE's OBS build service then, they build packages for many distributions.

Comment: You should ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

*(As you have GCC 4.4.7, I assume you're running RHEL 6.x, hopefully 6.9, the latest released version.)*

On RHEL 6 & 7, you can use *Red Hat Developer Toolset* (DTS) to install new(er) versions of various components, including GCC. DTS uses the 'software collection' packaging method, so the new version will be installed alongside the default version -- without creating any conflicts -- and you'll be able to user both.

If you require GCC 5.x, you will need to use DTS 4.x, which includes this version. If you just want a new version, then I would recommend using the newest DTS available, which is 6.1 (or the just released 7.0 beta), which include GCC 6.x and 7.x respectively.

See [Documentation for Red Hat Developer Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-developer-toolset/) for instructions on how to install and use DTS.

TL;DR:

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-server-rhscl-6-rpms
# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-6-server-optional-rpms
# yum -y install devtoolset-6-gcc
$ scl enable devtoolset-6 'gcc -o output_file source_file...'
```

(Note that support for DTS 4.x ends in Nov 2017, so using the newest version is really recommended.)